# How to create symlinks to multiple directories at once with shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I have an htaccess file that I want to create a symlink for in about 60 other directories. How can I do this in one line, instead of doing it over and over 60 times?

Example: `.htaccess` file is located in directory `public_html/directory/website_1/`

I want to create a symlink of it in:

```
public_html/directory/website_2/
public_html/directory/website_3/
public_html/directory/website_4/
public_html/directory/website_5/
```

But the directories are not numbered like that. Just using that as an example. All of the directories I want to copy the symlink into are in one main directory called `public_html/directory/` where `website_1 and website_2` etc reside.

etc etc

I'm using PuTTY.

and this is how I am currently creating symlinks.

```
ln -s ~/public_html/directory/website_1/.htaccess ./website_2/.htaccess
```

Then I have to redo this same line but change the `website_2` to `website_3` and so on 60 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `for` loop:

```
for dir in ./website_*
do
    [ "$dir" = "./website_1" ] && continue  # Skip the master file
    ln -s ~/public_html/directory/website_1/.htaccess "$dir"
done
```

I don't think there is a quicker way (unless you use a Perl script to do the job, or Python perhaps — but there'd likely be more debugging involved with them).

Comment: this worked. I had to use the wild card * like this `for dir in ./*-*
do` because in every directory there is a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly.
You have to create one then, copying it to multiple destinations.
But to copy to multiple destination, you have to use `cp -s` (`-s` for creating symlinks instead of copying source) one time per destination.

> The right way is to create the shell script to loop over destinations after created the first symlink

Comment: `cp` probably isn't a good way to do things here; it won't create symlinks, but will copy the material pointed at by the symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one-liner:
`cd public_html/directory; for i in *; do ln -s <NAME_WEB1>/.htaccess "$i"/.htaccess;done`

Comment: I entered the main directory and typed `for i in *; do ln -s <airsahara-in>/.htaccess "$i"/.htaccess;done` and then got this response about 60 times. `-bash: /.htaccess: Permission denied`.

Comment: the master .htaccess file is in airsahara-in/ directory and that directory is in the main directory of public_html/directory where all the other directories are at I'm trying to create the symlinks for.